# Firebug 1.5 showing 200 Aborted for Ajax requests

Tags: ajax, firebug, xmlhttprequest, firebug1.5

When I'm using Firebug 1.5, I'm getting 200 ABORTED errors on certain ajax requests. You can see this happen on [this demo page](http://wicketstuff.org/wicket14/ajax/autocomplete.0) by typing into the textfield.  The functionality of the site seems to work just fine even with these errors. Is it safe to simply ignore these errors?

This [wicket mailing list thread](http://old.nabble.com/Ajax-request-bug--to27324473.html#a27324571) seems to indicate that the wicket ajax code is doing what it should.  Also, this [firebug issue](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=2712) seems to indicate there may be some concern. Not sure what to think.

Comment: The firebug devs have indicated that the code on the sample I show actually does respond with an ABORT, and that the behavior is as expected.  They also indicate that this firebug behavior has caused lots of confusion and that the next release will go back to treating 200 aborts as they did before.  See http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=2712 for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like aborts on requests that already were coming back with an OK. Firebug will filter these out on some future release, see the code change here:

http://code.google.com/p/fbug/source/detail?r=6127

Answer (score 11):

I just spent 30 mins with a similar problem. While this is not an answer directly to the above, a google search for my problem got me here, so I thought I'd add it here in case it saves someone else some time. As always, my problem turned out be developer error. I was binding an ajax request to a submit button, but I'd forgotten to use preventDefault() on the button before making the XHR, so the request was being aborted as soon as the default behaviour for the button kicked in - sometimes before the response came back, sometimes not - but it would always report in firebug 1.5 to be aborted.

Comment: I had a similar problem attaching an Ajax event to a keydown event of the escape key.   In FF the escape key also kills the http request and so they were immediately aborted.   Calling .preventDefault() on the event stopped the propagation of the keydown event and solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am also encountering this. I can see it on your demo site above on every request, but also I see it on one of my sites. I didn't notice this before, and I am sure I would notice it since I stare at the console for hours everyday.  Gives some pretty mixed messages.

[image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/848795/Screen%20shot%202010-02-16%20at%2011.05.16%20PM.png]

I am using a mac with firebug 1.5. This bug has been reported on the firebug bug list id=2712 but seems to be going nowhere. It's a tricky one. I tend to notice it when i have 2 simultaneous requests fired off at the same time, and perhaps one preemptively returns before the other. But this shouldn't cause an Abort message.

Comment: It looks like the next release of Firebug will once again ignore 200 abort codes. See my comment to the question. http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=2712

Answer (score 0):

I saw your demo page with Firebug and seems to be working fine, there is no error to it and note that 200 response denotes that request was successful. It is not an error abort like you say.

[image]

Comment: Were you using FireBug 1.5, or some other version?  I'm running in Firefox on OSX snow leopard.

Comment: @Tauren: yes i am using 1.5 on xp sp2.

Comment: Strange that you don't see it.  A response in this thread says they can see it too: http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=2712 However, it looks like they think Firebug is doing the right thing in this case.

Comment: @Tauren: please see my answer again where i show the response i get, there is no error you mention

Comment: @Tauren: the error might be related to some other hidden tasks running or even your firefox or something

Comment: See my comment on the question above.